# hive.HiveImport: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist:

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop, hadoop2

I am trying to import MySQL database into Hive to analysis of large MySQL Data according to **[Blog](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/11/mysql-and-hadoop/)** there are  couple of ways to do this

1. ***Non realtime: Sqoop***
2. ***Realtime: Hadoop Applier for MySQL***

so I decided to go with the '*Non realtime*' approach and I have setup the Hadoop cluster with 4 node, Sqoop and Hive which working fine with following versions

**Name**        **Version**

***Apache Hadoop***   *2.6.0*

***Apache Hive***   *hive-0.14.0*

***Apache Sqoop***  *sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha*

Now when I am trying to import data using following command

**Import Command**

```
sqoop-import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/edgeowt --username root -P --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --hive-database edgeowt.db  --hive-overwrite
```

then I am getting following error

**Error**

```
INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: edgeowt.db
15/04/16 13:32:09 ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 88
```

I logged in with Hiveserver2 and check the database, but I can able to see the given database

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin>beeline
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 scott tiger org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> show databases;
+----------------+--+
| database_name  |
+----------------+--+
| default        |
| edgeowt        |
+----------------+--+
```

After looking into *HDFS file System web interface* I realize that the ***Owner of the DB is different***

```
Permission  Owner   Group       Size    Replication Block Size  Name
drwxr-xr-x  hduser  supergroup  0 B 0       0 B     candidate
drwxr-xr-x  scott   supergroup  0 B 0       0 B     edgeowt.db
drwxr-xr-x  scott   supergroup  0 B 0       0 B     hd_temperature
```

as I am trying to import the data using **hduser** and and the database is created using **scott** user.
I tried to grant **ALL** previlages to **hduser** on **edgeowt.db** using following command

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>GRANT ALL ON DATABASE edgeowt TO USER hduser;
```

and check with

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> SHOW GRANT ON DATABASE edgeowt;
+-----------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------+--+
| database  | table  | partition  | column  | principal_name  | principal_type  | privilege  | grant_option  |   grant_time   | grantor  |
+-----------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------+--+
| edgeowt   |        |            |         | admin           | ROLE            | ALL        | false         | 1429170366000  | scott    |
| edgeowt   |        |            |         | hduser          | USER            | ALL        | false         | 1429170906000  | scott    |
+-----------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+---------------+----------------+----------+--+
```

but unable to solve the error , So how can I solve this problem ? or any point to solve this will be helpful.

**~/.bashrc**

```
# Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

# Set hive home 
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

# Set HCatlog home 
export HCAT_HOME=$HIVE_HOME/hcatalog
export PATH=$PATH:$HCAT_HOME/bin

# Set Sqoop home
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
export SQOOP_HOME=/opt/sqoop
export SQOOP_CONF_DIR="$SQOOP_HOME/conf"
export SQOOP_CLASSPATH="$SQOOP_CONF_DIR"
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
```

***EDIT***

tried with following command still having same error

```
sqoop-import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/edgeowt --username root -P --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --hive-database edgeowt --hive-overwrite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the answer by myself while reading the forum discussion about the same issue ***[here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/UR0CaPVbqvQ)***.

***The issue was with the Hive Metastore configuration***, there are three types of Hive Metastore configurations

1. **Embedded Metastore (default metastore deployment mode).**
2. **Locall Metastore.**
3. **Remote Metastore.**

and my Hive Metastore configuration was the default one. As mention in cloudera documentation of **[Configuring the Hive Metastore](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html)**,
I change the metastore configuration from **Embedded (Default)** to ***Remote Metastore*** and its start working for me.

for More information of Metastore configuration use following documentation of Cloudera.

**[Configuring the Hive Metastore](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html)**

**Sqoop Command**

```
sqoop-import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/edgeowt --username root -P --hive-import --hive-database edgeowt --hive-overwrite -m 4
```

Answer (score 1):

> sqoop-import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/edgeowt --username root -P --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse **--hive-database** edgeowt.db --hive-overwrite

Change `--hive-database edgewot.db` to `--hive-table edgewot.db`, where `edgewot` is your hive database name and `db` is your hive tablename.

```
sqoop-import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X/edgeowt --username root -P --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --hive-table edgeowt.db  --hive-overwrite
```

> **NOTE:** There is no --hive-database options in sqoop-1.4.5. Please refer **table 8 Hive Arguments** of Section 7.2.11 in http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html

**--ALTERNATE METHOD--**

If sqoop import-all-tables fails, try the following steps:

**1.** Create a folder named `hivetables` in `/usr/local` (local filesystem). Change permissions for the folder `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/hivetables`.

**2.** Create a shell script named `sqoop-hive.sh` in `/usr/local/hivetables` and change permissions for this file `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/hivetables/sqoop-hive.sh`

**3.** Paste this in `sqoop-hive.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#tabfold="/usr/local/hivetables"
#cd $tabfold
mysql -u $1 -p$2 -N information_schema -e "select table_name from tables where table_schema = '$3'" > /usr/local/hivetables/tables.txt
HOSTFILE="/usr/local/hivetables/tables.txt"
for host in $(cat $HOSTFILE)
do
   $SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$3 --table $host --username $1 --password $2 --hive-import --hive-table $4.$host --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse
done
```

**4.** Execute the shell script as `sh /usr/local/hivetables/sqoop-hive.sh MYSQLUSERNAME MYSQLPASSWORD MYSQLDATABASE HIVEDATABASE`

> **NOTE:** The **mysql** command exports the table names in mysql databse into a text file. **For** loop reads the tables file and executes sqoop command for each table name.

Comment: Tried still same error 
error FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: edgeowt

Comment: sqoop-import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.49/edgeowt --username root -P --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --hive-table edgewot.db --hive-overwrite -m 4 

Error FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: edgewot

Comment: The error you are getting  may be due to `sqoop import-all-tables` command. I have updated my answer with alternate method using `sqoop import` command. Try it.

Comment: $ sh sqoop-hive.sh root `` edgeowt edgeowt
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Run it as `hduser` not as `root`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75476/discussion-between-ashish-jagtap-and-rajesh-n).

Answer (score 0):

did you  export hive_conf_dir in hive-env.sh

export HIVE_CONF_DIR="/etc/hive/conf"  ---you hive configuration path

Comment: thanks for reply I tried without .db extension still getting same error
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: edgeowt

Comment: yes I have set HIVE_CONF_DIR in my $HOME/.bashrc file check my updates

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error on the quickstart VM by cloudera using parcel mode.

I copied hive-site.xml to the sqoop conf directory :

```
sudo cp /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /etc/sqoop/conf/
```

That trick solved the problem.