# Oozie--FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: testnamespace

Tags: hadoop, oozie

​I get an error while running an Oozie workflow with Hive queries. 
Here is the workflow

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='reporting_W_errorAuditHiveQueryExe'>
<start to="hive_report_fork"/>
<fork name="hive_report_fork">
    <path start="hiveGSRLfile"/>
    <path start="hiveNGSRLfile"/>
    <path start="hiveNGsrlRAfile"/>
</fork>
<action name="hiveGSRLfile">
    <hive xmlns='uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2'>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <script>${dir}/gsrlQery.hql</script>
        <param>OutputDir=${jobOutput}</param>
    </hive>
    <ok to="joining"/>
    <error to="joining"/>
</action>
<action name="hiveNGSRLfile">
    <hive xmlns='uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2'>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <script>${dir}/nongsrlQuery.hql</script>
        <param>OutputDir=${jobOutput}</param>
    </hive>
    <ok to="joining"/>
    <error to="joining"/>
</action>
<action name="hiveNGsrlRAfile">
    <hive xmlns='uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2'>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <script>${dir}/nongsrlRAQuery.hql</script>
        <param>OutputDir=${jobOutput}</param>
    </hive>
    <ok to="joining"/>
    <error to="joining"/>
</action>
<join name= "joining" to="Success"/>
<action name="Success">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${failureEmailToAddress}</to>
        <subject>Success</subject>
        <body>
            The workflow ${wf:name()} with id ${wf:id()} failed
            [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}].
        </body>
    </email>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
<action name="failure">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${failureEmailToAddress}</to>
        <subject>Failure</subject>
        <body>
            The workflow ${wf:name()} with id ${wf:id()} failed
            [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}].
        </body>
    </email>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Workflow failed</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

And here is the oozie properties file

```
oozie.wf.application.path=${deploymentPath}/workflows/errorAuditHiveQueryExe.xml
deploymentPath=/user/amin/deploy_178
jobTracker=localhost:8032
nameNode=hdfs://nameservice1
dir=${deploymentPath}/data-warehouse/temp
failureEmailToAddress=amin@dnb.com
jobOutput=${dir}
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
```

Here is the error I get:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: testnamespace 
Intercepting System.exit(10072)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [10072]
```

However the namespace exist and I can query the tables inside it.

What could be wrong here? Please help.
I use CDH 5.5.2 Running Hive 1.0

Comment: Have you checked out this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670830/hive-hiveimport-failed-semanticexception-error-10072-database-does-not-exis

Comment: Yes I did already but that is not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 3):

After a tireless research on the internet I was able to crack the solution for the issue.
I have added a configuration to use the metastore server for the Hive job and it worked.

Here is what I did to the Hive action.

```
....
<hive xmlns='uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2'>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
                    <value>thrift://10.155.1.63:9083</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>${dir}/gsrlQery.hql</script>
            <param>OutputDir=${jobOutput}</param>
        </hive>
....
```

Note: replace the hive metatore ip accordingly if you are trying to fix a similar problem. To get the metastore details check the hive-site.xml file located in /etc/hive/conf dir.

Credit: [MapR](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Run+Hive+Jobs+with+Oozie)